# TINYMCE - Put any font that I want in a textbox ? Possible ?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Is it possible to add textbox and put any font that I choose to in addition to the Drop down list of the fonts in TinyMCE ?

```
fontsize_formats: "8px 9px 10px 11px 12px 14px 16px 18px 20px 22px 24px 36px",
lineheight_formats: "8px 9px 10px 11px 12px 14px 16px 18px 20px 22px 24px 26px 36px",
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify a set of fonts to be added. From the official docs:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar: 'fontselect',
  font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;AkrutiKndPadmini=Akpdmi-n'
});
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/

Check the link to the docs it has plenty of information there.

Comment: Thanks , but I meant any font size that I choose to (as the user).
I don't want a set of fonts , I want any font (for example : the user chooses to 150px/220px/330px).

Comment: How about adding the following parameter:

theme_concrete_font_sizes : "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"

If this adds the dropdown you can modify it later to fit your needs. Check the latest answer from here:

https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/usage/add-font-sizes-to-drop-down-list-in-tinymce

Comment: You're still referring to something else , not to my problem.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE (as it stands today) does not allow for an input field on the toolbar so you can't provide a field where you enter any number you like (akin to what Word allows).

You could create a custom toolbar button (or menu option) that opens a dialog and then ask for that value.  Once you do that you can insert the appropriate span tag.

The following fiddle shows how to inject the finished HTML - all you have to do is add the UI to ask for the font size first:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/M3gaab